# 405 Error using slash command handler Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I got a `405: Method Not Allowed` error when I was running the slash command builder.
There's the code:

```js
const { glob } = require("glob");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const globPromise = promisify(glob);

/**
 * @param {Client} client
 */
module.exports = async (client) => {
    // Commands
    const commandFiles = await globPromise(`${process.cwd()}/commands/**/*.js`);
    commandFiles.map((value) => {
        const file = require(value);
        const splitted = value.split("/");
        const directory = splitted[splitted.length - 2];

        if (file.name) {
            const properties = { directory, ...file };
            client.commands.set(file.name, properties);
        }
    });

    // Events
    const eventFiles = await globPromise(`${process.cwd()}/events/*.js`);
    eventFiles.map((value) => require(value));

    // Slash Commands
    const slashCommands = await globPromise(
        `${process.cwd()}/SlashCommands/*/*.js`
    );

    const arrayOfSlashCommands = [];
    slashCommands.map((value) => {
        const file = require(value);
        if (!file?.name) return;
        client.slashCommands.set(file.name, file);

        if (["MESSAGE", "USER"].includes(file.type)) delete file.description;
        if (file.userPermissions) file.defaultPermission = false;
        arrayOfSlashCommands.push(file);
    });

    client.on("ready", async () => {
        // Register for a single guild
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("1014471738844790844");
        await guild.commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands).then((cmd) => {
            const getRoles = (commandName) => {
                const permissions = arrayOfSlashCommands.find((x) => x.name === commandName).userPermissions;

                if (!permissions) return null;  
                return guild.roles.cache.filter(x => x.permissions.has(permissions) && !x.managed);
            };

            const fullPermissions = cmd.reduce((accumulator, x) => {
                const roles = getRoles(x.name);
                if (!roles) return accumulator;

                const permissions = roles.reduce((a, v) => {
                    return [
                        ...a,
                        {
                            id: v.id,
                            type: 'ROLE',
                            permission: true,
                        }
                    ];

                }, []);

                return [
                    ...accumulator,
                    {
                        id: x.id,
                        permission: permissions,
                    }
                ];
            }, []);

            guild.commands.permissions.set({ fullPermissions });

        });

        // Register for all the guilds the bot is in
        // await client.application.commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands);
    });

    // mongoose
    const { mongooseConnectionString } = require('../config.json')
    if (!mongooseConnectionString) return;

    mongoose.connect(mongooseConnectionString).then(() => console.log('Connected to mongodb'));

};
```

There's the `interactionCreate.js` file:

```js
const client = require("../index");

client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
    // Slash Command Handling
    if (interaction.isCommand()) {
        await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: false }).catch(() => { });

        const cmd = client.slashCommands.get(interaction.commandName);
        if (!cmd)
            return interaction.followUp({ content: "An error has occurred " });

        const args = [];

        for (let option of interaction.options.data) {
            if (option.type === "SUB_COMMAND") {
                if (option.name) args.push(option.name);
                option.options?.forEach((x) => {
                    if (x.value) args.push(x.value);
                });
            } else if (option.value) args.push(option.value);
        }
        interaction.member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.user.id);

        if (!interaction.member.permissions.has(cmd.userPermissions || [])) return interaction.followUp({ content: `Error: Mission Permissions.` });

        cmd.run(client, interaction, args);
    }

    // Context Menu Handling
    if (interaction.isContextMenu()) {
        await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: false });
        const command = client.slashCommands.get(interaction.commandName);
        if (command) command.run(client, interaction);
    }
});
```

And there's the error I got:

```js
C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\ROBO_Head-v2\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: 405: Method Not Allowed
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\ROBO_Head-v2\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\ROBO_Head-v2\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager.set (C:\Users\pines\OneDrive\桌面\ROBO_Head-v2\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager.js:186:18) {
  method: 'put',
  path: '/applications/991997852538634311/guilds/1014471738844790844/commands/permissions',
  code: 0,
  httpStatus: 405,
  requestData: { json: [], files: [] }
}
```

Discord.js version is `13.11.0`, bot has administrator permission on the server.
Please help me solve this.

Comment: Have you checkmarked the `application.commands` scope in your developer portal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [403 Error when setting application command permissions on Discord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72048570/403-error-when-setting-application-command-permissions-on-discord)